# Encapsulating Shiro Subject

Tags: java, security, servlets, shiro

I would like to encapsulate Apache Shiro in a Servlet environment. I want to create MySecurityUtils and use Shiro SecurityUtils.getSubject in a static method. My question is whether this is a correct way to use SecurityUtils.getSubject method in a static method. Can this cause any problems in multithreaded servlet environment?

MySecurityUtils.java

```
import org.apache.shiro.subject.Subject;
import org.apache.shiro.SecurityUtils;

public class MySecurityUtils {

    public static MyUser getUser() {
        Subject currentUser = SecurityUtils.getSubject();
        MyUser myUser = new MyUser(currentUser);
        ...
    }
}
```

MyUser.java

```
public class MyUser {
   // ... constructors
   public boolean isPermitted(..) {subject.isPermitted(...)}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After feedback of Sotirios I changed my code as follows

```
 public class SecurityHelper {
     public static boolean isAuthenticated(){
      Subject currentUser = SecurityUtils.getSubject();
      return currentUser.isAuthenticated();
     }
     public static void checkPermission(String permissionCode){
          Subject currentUser = SecurityUtils.getSubject();
          currentUser.checkPermission(permissionCode);
     }
     public static void checkPermission(String... permissionCodes){
          Subject currentUser = SecurityUtils.getSubject();
          currentUser.checkPermissions(permissionCodes);
     }
     ... and so on
```

I encapsulate all application logic in a Helper class.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you would want to do this, but for your question's sake, this would be fine.

In a web context, Shiro's `SecurityUtils#getSubject()` returns a different `Subject` instance per request. Obviously if the subject is logged in, the credentials will be copied over (from session) to the new `Subject` instance. You are pretty much doing the same thing by returning a new `MyUser` instance on each call to `getUser()`.

Careful though, if you call `getUser()` twice in the same request, you will get a different `MyUser` instance. However, the internal `Subject` will be the same. It can be problematic if you are doing logic other than delegating in your `MyUser` class.

Comment: I would like to add additional application specific check to the MyUser object. MyUser will be immutable and the methods of the Subject method will be accesses via delagate methods. I think in that case it would be fine or?

Comment: Because you are returning a new instance each time from your `MySecurityUtils` class, careful if you need to get the User more than once per request. You will be operating on different `MyUser` instances.